# Apache cannot access the directory that is included in the conf file

Tags: python, django, apache

I have a directory called `media` in my `django` application. I've declared the directory in my apache conf file, and the permissions of the directory and all of its files are 755. but when I try to load an image from it's url apache says:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /media/foo.jpg on this server.
```

here is my apache conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

Alias /static/ /root/websites/FJSharif/static/
<Directory /root/websites/FJSharif/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /media/ /root/websites/FJSharif/media/
<Directory /root/websites/fJSharif/media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /root/websites/FJSharif/FJSharif>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess FJSharif python-path=/root/websites/FJSharif:/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

WSGIProcessGroup FJSharif
WSGIScriptAlias / /root/websites/FJSharif/FJSharif/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

when I try to load this url:

```
http://example.com/media/foo.img
```

I get the 403 Forbidden error.

EDIT:

Apache can find the files in `/static/` directory but not the files in `/media/` directory!

Comment: What are the permissions of the *files* Apache is trying to access (e.g. foo.img)? Do they allow read by users other than the owner?

Comment: yes, the permissions are all 755

Comment: Have you restarted the apache process after editing the config file (or at least forced it to reload its configuration)? What output do you see in the Apache log files? Also, what does django report when the debug setting is `True`?

Comment: yes, I've restarted apache after editing the config file. django's debug setting is True. but the page does not show any django error page. the django version is 1.8.5.

Comment: Can you check that `suexec` is not getting in your way and/or that the SELinux security context for the directories and files the server is trying to access is correct?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92571/discussion-between-ray-and-navid777).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion, we eliminated a few possibilities, but it's still worth double-checking the config file for typos (e.g. paths are case-sensitive). A lot of people are often bit by this easily missed detail.